# Why was Mom never sent to the Near Death Star?

Tags: futurama

Throughout the series we see that Mom and the Peofessor worked together and had a relationship. This would make Mom either the same age has the Professor, or older (she's looked as ancient in the flashbacks as current time). So why hasn't Mom been summoned to the big retirement home in the sky?

Comment: who do you think supplies the robots that administer the near death star?

Comment: Silence! The robot elders may have built them!

Comment: Silence! I hadn't thought of that.

Comment: Silence! Who do you think built the Robot Elders!

Comment: Corruption. She is very rich, and bribed someone (Nixon? herself for all we know, she controls a lot) to keep her out. I'm more wondering why Ogden Wernstrom wasn't there, or Fry for that matter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Out of universe: never directly addressed. Most likely, a result of Mom having been introduced very early on, while The Near Death Star was introduced somewhat later.

In universe: never directly addressed. Speculating: Mom is very rich and very powerful. It is difficult to force such people to do anything they don't want to do. Further, as Kevin Milner points out in the comments, the robots who enforce the mandatory retirement age are most likely manufactured by Mom's Friendly Robots. As we see in the episode [Mother's Day](http://theinfosphere.org/Mother's_Day), this gives Mom considerable influence over them.

Comment: The robots could have been commissioned by the robot elders, but the NDS was mentioned in an earlier season when the professor was taken there

Comment: I forgot about the earlier NDS episode. Corrected.

Comment: Also, the robot elders seem less likely; they would be disinclined to spend their limited resources on such a venture, and even less inclined to keep their charges alive.